# What do you do when you find out some one has created hundreds of low quality backlinks to your website?

Tags: seo, backlinks, negative-seo, disavow-links

For the last couple of months, I noticed that the backlinks to a website I manage as reported by https://semrush.com increased by more than 800. When I checked, I found that there were hundreds of new spammy links originating from one website with the same link description (all from https://wptavern.com). I understand that this could be coming from scammers or spammers or even competitors. The spammers create a problem and then offer a service to resolve it. I guess that this could be the reason why someone would do something like this, but I am not sure.

I just want these backlinks removed so that I can have a clean slate. My website is https://peakpmgt.com.  What is the best course of action?

Comment: Are you seeing any search engine ranking problems that could be related to these new links?

Comment: So far, none I can talk of, but I am afraid of penalties as all the links are pointing to one page. They are also all no-follow links.

Comment: You can disavow the links - https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-disavow-links/

Comment: Thanks David. The ahref blog is of very high quality. The key takeaway for me is that I should proceed with caution and consider waiting for a penalty before disavowing the links. Google apparently has a way of devaluing such links.  I checked the anchor cloud and it is very revealing with words like "purchase viagra " dominating.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do nothing (it probably won't hurt you) or else log into Google Search Console and disavow the links.

Comment: You should only disavow links when Google has taken manual action against your site for spammy links according to [the documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en).   Google has said that using disavow when there is no penalty is likely to do harm and won't do any good.